# Is toes lifting from the ground during a squat considered bad form

Tags: overhead-squat

Whenever I go squatting, my toes lift off the ground while my heel is planted on the ground. Is this considered to be bad?  I have heard that lifting the heel off the ground during a squat is bad, but I have never  heard  lifting of the toes to be bad. plz help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Toes lifting off the ground is an indication that your weight is being held too far back, towards the heel of the foot rather than over the mid-foot. Your weight should feel evenly distributed between heel and ball.

Lifting the toes is not as bad as lifting the heels (which completely changes the mechanics of the lift, shifting load from the glutes onto the quadriceps), but it does indicate a balance problem and perhaps suggest that you are at risk of tipping backwards.

Comment: So how do I get rid of this. Plz help.

Comment: Focus on feeling the weight balanced between the balls and heels of your feet. If you feel that there is more weight on your heels, you need to shift your weight forwards, probably by leaning your torso over more. Don't try to keep your chest upright.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, toes lifting off of the ground during a squat is bad form.  For stability (safety), you must keep the whole sole of each foot on the ground during the entire movement.